# How to install egg file with easy_install?

Tags: hpc, easy-install, egg

On a HPC node, I have a file named `pysdf-0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg`.

I found a Nvidia Manual to install this file using `python -m easy_install pysdf-0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg`.

However, when I run this command I get the following error.

```sh
(/scratch/s.1915438/modulus) [s.1915438@sl1 eggs]$ python -m easy_install pysdf-0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg
/scratch/s.1915438/modulus/bin/python: No module named easy_install
```

Similarly, if I use `pip install` as follows

```sh
(/scratch/s.1915438/modulus) [s.1915438@sl1 eggs]$ python -m pip install pysdf-0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysdf-0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pysdf-0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg
```

I do not have admin access on HPC server to use `sudo apt`. My python is installed at  `/scratch/s.1915438/modulus/bin/python` on the HPC machine.

Does anyone knows why it says `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 months, I figured out how to do this. So, `egg` files can be installed using something called `easy_install` which was [depreciated](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/issues/493) back in 2019. The last version of `setuptools` that supported `easy_install` was `setuptools 42.0.0.`.

So, you need to downgrade to that version as follows.

```bash
pip3 install setuptools==42.0.0
```

And then install the `egg` files using the following command.

```bash
python3 -m easy_install example.egg
```

If you wish to upgrade the `setuptools` to the latest version, then type

```bash
pip3 install setuptools --upgrade
```